# Whats wrong with the DB query code in Console Kernel in Laravel PHP?

Tags: database, laravel-8, kernel-module

I'm trying to figure out why the DB query is not being executed at all. I did everything according to the documentation, but it doesn't work. I run this code in a controller and everything works great. Below is the code that I wrote in the kernel file. Please help with a solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{


    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('sitemap:generate')
                 ->daily();

        //      
        
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('users')->whereNotNull('subscription_ends_at')->where('subscription_ends_at', '<', Carbon::now())->update(['stripe_account' => 567]);                          
        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to create a command file for execute the logic of DB query instead of doing inside kernal file.

I think you will solve your problem by creating separate command file and implement your DB query logic there.

create a command by

```
php artisan make:command StripeAccountUpdate
```

Add below code in the `App/Console/Commands/StripeAccountUpdate.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class StripeAccountUpdate extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'stripeaccountupdate:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Cron job for update user table stripe_account column';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('users')->whereNotNull('subscription_ends_at')->where('subscription_ends_at', '<', Carbon::now())->update(['stripe_account' => 567]);
        \Log::info('Cronjob run for update user table stripe_account');
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And finally in your `kernal.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('sitemap:generate')
                 ->daily();
        $schedule->command('stripeaccountupdate:cron')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What kind of "command file" do you talk about? Why exactly shouldn't this be done in the given class?